# Java Game Raycasting: Closest intersection between Line and Rectangles

Tags: java, raycasting

Im having problems with my game. The thing i wanne do is draw a line and if the line intersects with the surroundings it calculates the shortest distance between the surroundings and the player and places a red point(see picture)

When i run my program with one line it works perfect but when i send lines to all the corners of the surroundings some lines go through the surroundings.
(sorry for bad english)

P.S. 
**Line:** line between mario and the surrounding points
**LineSur:** the lines that describes the border or the surroundings
And im trying to do something like this
 http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/

[image]

Does someone have an idea whats going wrong here?

Here is my code

```
public void Lighting(){
                ListIterator<Surroundings> surrounding = m.getSurrounding();
                Line.clear();
                LineSur.clear();
                Point.clear();
            rememDistance=1500;

            while (surrounding.hasNext() ){
                Surroundings rectangle = surrounding.next(); 
                Rectangle sur = new Rectangle((int) rectangle.grootte().getX(),(int) rectangle.grootte().getY()-13,(int) rectangle.grootte().getWidth(),(int) rectangle.grootte().getHeight());

                Line.add(new Lines((int) sur.getX()                 , (int) sur.getY()                  , (int) sur.getX()                 , (int) (sur.getY()+sur.getHeight())));
                Line.add(new Lines((int) sur.getX()                 , (int) sur.getY()                  , (int) (sur.getX()+sur.getWidth()), (int) sur.getY()));
                Line.add(new Lines((int) (sur.getX()+sur.getWidth()), (int) (sur.getY()+sur.getHeight()), (int) (sur.getX()+sur.getWidth()), (int) sur.getY()));
                Line.add(new Lines((int) (sur.getX()+sur.getWidth()), (int) (sur.getY()+sur.getHeight()), (int) sur.getX()                 , (int) (sur.getY()+sur.getHeight())));

                LineSur.add(new LinesSur((int) m.player.getxPositie(), (int) m.player.getyPositie(), (int) sur.getX()                 , (int) sur.getY()));
                LineSur.add(new LinesSur((int) m.player.getxPositie(), (int) m.player.getyPositie(), (int) (sur.getX()+sur.getWidth()), (int) sur.getY()));
                LineSur.add(new LinesSur((int) m.player.getxPositie(), (int) m.player.getyPositie(), (int) sur.getX()                 , (int) (sur.getY()+sur.getHeight())));
                LineSur.add(new LinesSur((int) m.player.getxPositie(), (int) m.player.getyPositie(), (int) (sur.getX()+sur.getWidth()), (int) (sur.getY()+sur.getHeight())));
            }

//Problem is probably coming from these for loops
                int distance=0;

                for(int i=0;i < LineSur.size();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j < Line.size();j++){
                        Line2D.Double lineI = LineSur.get(i).points();

                        if(lineI.intersectsLine(Line.get(j).points())){
                            Point2D IntPoint = getIntersection(Line.get(j).points(),lineI);
                            Point.add(new Points((int) IntPoint.getX(),(int) IntPoint.getY()));


                            distance = (int) Point.get(Point.size()-1).point2D().distance(m.player.getxPositie(), m.player.getyPositie());

                            if(rememDistance > distance){
                                rememDistance = distance;
                                System.out.println(rememDistance);
                                Point.get(Point.size()-1).distance= rememDistance;
                            }
                            else{Point.remove((Point.size()-1));}

                        }
                    }
                    for(int k=0;k < Point.size();k++){
                        if(rememDistance == Point.get(k).distance){
                            Point.get(k).shortest=true;}
                    }
                    rememDistance = 1500;
                }


                for(int i=0;i < Point.size();i++){
                    if(Point.get(i).shortest==false){Point.remove(i);}
                }

    }
```

and heres the getIntersection method

```
public Point2D getIntersection(final Line2D.Double line1, final Line2D.Double line2){
        final double x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4;
        x1 = line1.x1; y1 = line1.y1; x2 = line1.x2; y2 = line1.y2;
        x3 = line2.x1; y3 = line2.y1; x4 = line2.x2; y4 = line2.y2;

        final double x = ((x2 - x1)*(x3*y4 - x4*y3) - (x4 - x3)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1)) /((x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4));
        final double y = ((y3 - y4)*(x1*y2 - x2*y1) - (y1 - y2)*(x3*y4 - x4*y3)) /((x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4));

        return new Point2D.Double(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to perform Raycasting. If your code doesn't detect the first found element, it's because something is wrong in your collision detection: either the surrounding are too small for the detection step, or you have some more serious bug.

Comment: `rectangle.grootte().getY()-13` What's so significant about 13?

Comment: @AndyTurner was a quick fix from a previous error need to still fix that good call, but its nothing special.

Comment: The fact that all of your red dots lie on rectangles implies that the intersection logic is correct; it is just the detection of the shortest distance which is not. I am not sure, but I think that the for loop over `k` should be outside the loop which currently contains it.

Comment: @AndyTurner it needs to be in there because i need a red point for each line coming from mario.

Comment: one extra thing. If i move a pixel to the left some of the false dots may be gone and some extra may be there

Comment: @AndyTurner found it the last for loop had to be between the for loop facepalm. Thx u sent me in the right direction

Comment: NP, pleased you worked it out.